# Backing Up OS X Server to Local Time Machine Server Folder

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup, server.app

I've setup Time Machine Backup services on Mavericks Server. I want to backup the backup server itself using Time Machine, but to the folder that I setup "Time Machine Backups" where all the other backups are being stored, instead of backing up to the root drive.

The only option I have when I select a disk using the server's Time Machine configuration is the drive itself, and not the "Time Machine Backups" folder I see from remote machines.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. Backing up to a local volume (what you're having the server do) uses a slightly different backup format than a network backup (what your server is allowing clients to do). With a local volume backup, the backups are stored inside a folder named Backups.backupdb which is at the root of the backup volume (*not* in a subfolder). With a network backup, the backup is stored inside a disk image, and the Backups.backupdb folder is at the root of the volume inside that. Because the network backup is wrapped in a disk image, that image can be almost anywhere (volume root, folder, subfolder, whatever); but this flexibility does not exist for a local volume backup.

Comment: Couldn't you *mount* that image, locally to the server, and then backup to the mount-point? (I mean, all Time Machine cares about, is ‘an HFS+ volume with `/Backups.backupdb` at the root.’ If you mount the disk-image, you should satisfy that requirement, right?)

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE: I've seen conflicting reports about this; for example, [this Mac OS X Hints entry](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20140308141622774) describes one way of hacking it, with another (closer to what you describe) given in the comments... along with replies from people who couldn't get it to work. There's also [another question on askdifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34391/use-a-network-time-machine-drive-locally) along these lines... and a (deleted) comment from someone who coudn't get it to work. So go ahead and try, but I don't know if it'll work.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you point the OSX Server's Local time machine to its own share?

Like point it to afp://osx server ip

Or is it not possible to mount a local share locally?

Comment: Please rephrase your answer to answer the question instead of asking clarifying questions.